# Container view on button click in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, popup

How to display container view on button click in background (like alert view) in objective-c? Please provide steps wise answer as I am a beginner. I have login button in view controller and I want to display popup message on login button in a container view without hiding Current view controller. Also ok and cancel button in container view.

Comment: Do you want the customized alert or default alertView on click of button?
And which language you prefer? Objective C or Swift ?

Comment: customized alert in objective c

Answer (score 0):

It is a long process to describe. So I suggest to take a look [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-creating-a-custom-alert-view--mobile-16842). Here step wise procedure is given. For general idea steps are

1. Create a new UIView class (Select Project -> NewFile -> source ->
   cocoa touch -> UIView from the drop down)file and named it AlertView
   or anything relevant to any naming convention.
2. Design the container view inside the UIView class recently created.
3. Use the delegate or completion block for button action.
4. Import the Customized alert view in the ViewController where you
   want to show the customized alert.